# SSH http Tunnel zabbix

Tags: networking, ssh

A monitoring server with an ip address `158.23.22.12` is running zabbix.
Only ssh port-forward is open for public.
To view zabbix is via `http://<host>/zabbix`

How do I tunnel via ssh to `158.23.22.12` and open it from my browser local machine here?

Local machine here is OSX or Ubuntu

I've tried:

1. `ssh -D 8080 -i PATH_TO_KEY/key.pem username@158.23.22.12`
2. it connects like usual ssh in the terminal
3. Open up firefox and then setting and then set manual proxy configuration
4. What do i set on the http proxy and port field?
5. What do i type on the browser url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not seem to be Zabbix-specific, but the following should work:

```
ssh -L 8888:127.0.0.1:80 -i PATH_TO_KEY/key.pem username@158.23.22.12
```

That will port-forward port 80 from the localhost (from the 158.23.22.12 perspective) to port 8888 on the machine running `ssh`. Then the web interface can be accessed by opening `http://localhost:8888` in the browser.